# SSH Authentication in git2go

Tags: go, libgit2

I'm working on learning Go as my first compiled language (coming from php/python). My first project was a small POST hook listener for Bitbucket, which fetches and then checks out a Git repository via `os/exec`. I'm now trying to replace the `os/exec` calls with [git2go](https://github.com/libgit2/git2go). I'm running into a snag with the authentication, though. I have the following code:

```
package main

import (
    git "github.com/libgit2/git2go"
    "log"
)

func main() {

    _, Cred := git.NewCredSshKey("git","~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub","~/.ssh/id_rsa","")
    log.Println(Cred.Type())
    gitH,err := git.OpenRepository(".")
    if (err != nil) {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    remotes,err := gitH.ListRemotes()
    if (err != nil) {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    log.Println(remotes)
    origin,err := gitH.LoadRemote("origin")
    if (err != nil) {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    err = origin.Fetch(nil,"")
    if (err != nil) {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

When I run this I get `authentication required but no callback set`.

Looking at the [docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/libgit2/git2go), it looks like I need to add a call to `origin.SetCallbacks()` which expects a `RemoteCallbacks` struct. `RemoteCallbacks` has the function `CredentialsCallback` which returns an int and a `Cred` pointer. Since `NewCredSshKey` returns the same values, I tried adding the following:

```
var cb git.RemoteCallbacks
cb.CredentialsCallback = git.NewCredSshKey("git","~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub","~/.ssh/id_rsa","")
origin.SetCallbacks(cb)
```

which gives the errors `multiple-value git.NewCredSshKey() in single-value context` and
`cannot use cb (type git.RemoteCallbacks) as type *git.RemoteCallbacks in function argument`.

I think I'm completely misunderstanding how this works, and I haven't been able to find any examples using this library. Tips or pointers to some examples would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Couple of things:

`CredentialsCallback` needs to be set to a function that matches it's signature, not the output of such a function. However, the signature for `NewCredSshKey` isn't correct in the first place, only its return values match. The correct signature is:

```
func(url string, username_from_url string, allowed_types CredType) (int, *Cred)
```

The second error `cannot use cb (type git.RemoteCallbacks) as type *git.RemoteCallbacks` is because you need a pointer to a `RemoteCallbacks`.

Either declare and initialize it as a pointer:

```
cb := &git.RemoteCallbacks{}
// or alternatively 
// cb := new(git.RemoteCallbacks)
```

or take the address of when passing it as an argument:

```
origin.SetCallbacks(&cb)
```